# How do you download a file using the jxbrowser library?

Tags: java, download, jxbrowser

I'm using the jxbrowser library and I have a download link. For some reason there is no download shown.

```
        browser.setDownloadHandler(new DownloadHandler() {
            public boolean allowDownload(DownloadItem download) {
                download.addDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadUpdated(DownloadEvent event) {
                        DownloadItem download = event.getDownloadItem();
                        download.setDestinationFile(new File("C:/Users/"
                                + System.getProperty("user.name")
                                + "/Desktop/" + title));
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        });

        browser.loadURL(downloadURL);
```

Comment: Lots of things could be wrong.  For example, is the URL correct?  Is the remote site blocking / refusing your download?  Do you need to authenticate? Etcetera, etcetera.  You need to find / provide more evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but if you compare your code to the sample here:

- http://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/samples#TOC-File-Downloads

it looks like you are setting the destination for the download after the download has completed.  Try setting it in the download handler rather than the download event listener.